# How to know which Html video has ended?

Tags: javascript

I have multiple videos on a page. When a user clicks a video and it finishes playing, I want to get a value from an input and display that value. This is what I have right now:

> HTML

```
<input type='text' name='profileUsername' value='<?php echo $username; ?>' hidden>
<video width="320" height="240" id='video' controls>
   <source src="videos/<?php echo $row['video'] ?>" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

The above is a PHP while Loop

> JS

```
document.getElementById('video')[0].addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);

function myHandler(e) {
    alert("Hello");
    // What you want to do after the event
}
```

Comment: show the input and explain what you want to do

Comment: `and display it` where ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value from DOM element in **javascript**:

```
document.getElementById('textbox_id').value
```

you can get the element by `className` or by `tagName`(input) or by `Name`

You have to `addEventListener` to each video

so..

```
    var videos= document.getElementsByTagName("videos");
     for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
       videos[i].addEventListener("ended", function(event) {
          var target = event.target;
          var parent = target.parentElement; // here you sepose to get the element above the video (the input)
       });
     }
```

Here is explain for finding element:https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp

Comment: if you need more help you can write me

Comment: in your case `document.getElementByName('profileUsername').value`

Comment: This is what i had before but it does not seem to work when all the id are the same because of the loop

Comment: can you explain? you have a lot of input with the same `id` do you put id dinamiclly or hardcoded?

Comment: it is hard codded in the php loop

Comment: and you want the first one -- `document.getElementById('video')[0]`?

Comment: I mean `[0]` is the first...??

Comment: lets say there 6 videos on the page and they could play any of them how would i get the on they are playing?

Comment: you want `addEventListener` to all the videos and when one of the end then show the input above the ended video?

Comment: for good answer do this section warp in some div(the loop inside the div)?

Comment: OK this worked, one more thing how can i get the ended video src?

Comment: @ashlast from the `event`.... I realy appricate if you up vote and mark the answer

Comment: ooooh i founf something `this.currentSrc` this is the source of video